# Values from textbox array not updating

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in this forum and I'm having a hard time updating selected value from checkbox coming from the textbox value.

Scenario:

I want to update selected items, For example, I want to update Item-2 and the textbox from item received will be enabled, I will enter a number for example 1 and the textbox from total receive will automatically sum using AJAX.

The problem is after submitting the value from total receive the records that were updating is blank, but when I try to check and print_r the value is there.

And one more thing if all checkboxes are checked and enter a number for each item received, the value that it only get is the last value and will be updated will all selected checkbox.

Notes:

- The checkbox is an array
- Textbox from total receive is an array

**Here's my UI:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
public function recitem_insert(){

$this->load->model('dbquery');    

$check = $this->input->post('check');    
$total_rec = $_POST['total_rec'];


if(isset($check)){ //Check if check is checked    

  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($total_rec);$j++){    

    $updateData = array('rec_qty' => $total_rec[$j] );                                                        
    $this->dbquery->modUpdatedynamicval('tblstock', 'id', $updateData, $check[$i]);

       }        
   }//end for loop    

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Successfully Added!');
        window.close();
        </script>";        

}else{ //End If
      echo 'Please select a checkbox';
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>user/recitem_insert">

<div class="box">
<div class="box-header">
<h3 class="box-title">System ID: <b><?php echo $process_id; ?></b></h3>
</div>
<!-- /.box-header -->
<div class="box-body">
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Item Code</th>
<th>Item Description</th>
<th>Required QTY Order</th>
<th>Last QTY Recieve</th>
<th>Item Recieve</th>
<th>Total Recieve</th>



</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php                   

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblstock where process_id = '$process_id'");
foreach ($query->result() as $row){                                       
?>  

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="opt" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="valueChanged()"> </td>
<td><?php echo $row->item_code; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->qty_order; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->rec_qty; ?></td>

<input type="hidden" name="last_item_rec[]"  value="<?php echo $row->rec_qty;  ?>">

<td><input type="text" name="item_rec[]"  id="txt" disabled=""></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="total_rec[]"></td>  


</tr>

<?php 

}
?>  

</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>

<div class="box-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

**Model:**

```
public function modUpdatedynamicval($table, $column, $data, $equal_to){

$this->db->where($column, $equal_to);
$this->db->update($table, $data);         

}
```

### Edit

Let's assume:

I've input 1 in item_receive textbox one and the total receive will be 10,
2 in item_receive textbox two and the total receive will be 11, 
3 in item_receive textbox three and the total receive will be 12,

[image]

**CODE:**

```
$check = $this->input->post('check');   
$total_rec = $_POST['total_rec'];

echo 'Check Value';
print_r($check);

echo '<br><br>';

echo 'Total Recieve';
print_r($total_rec);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Check ValueArray ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 

Total RecieveArray ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 )
```

But If I only input the second textbox here's the output:

```
Check ValueArray ( [0] => 2 ) 

Total RecieveArray ( [0] => [1] => 11 [2] => )
```

Comment: If you are using Ajax than add it your code

Comment: But I need this in normal submit.. :(

Comment: what is value After submitting array?

Comment: if checkbox 1 is selected the value submiited is blank, checkbox 2 also blank but if checbox 3 give a correct value submitted.

Comment: So, Can you please share your full code and table structure

Comment: can you show us your $_POST array with checked 1, 2,3 ?

Comment: I've edit my question.. Please see it on the below of the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are having a problem to determine which input index is which on the back end. You could set an index key on each of the input like this :

```
<tbody>

<?php                   

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblstock where process_id = '$process_id'");
foreach ($query->result() as $key => $row){           //added key to be used as inputs key                             
?>  

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="opt" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="valueChanged()"> </td>
<td><?php echo $row->item_code; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->qty_order; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->rec_qty; ?></td>

<input type="hidden" name="last_item_rec[<?php echo $key ?>]"  value="<?php echo $row->rec_qty;  ?>">

<td><input type="text" name="item_rec[<?php echo $key ?>]"  id="txt" disabled=""></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="total_rec[<?php echo $key ?>]"></td>  


</tr>

<?php 

}
?>  

</tbody>
```

After that, then replace the for loop :

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($total_rec);$j++){    

    $updateData = array('rec_qty' => $total_rec[$j] );                                                        
    $this->dbquery->modUpdatedynamicval('tblstock', 'id', $updateData, $check[$i]);

    }        
}//end for loop
```

With this foreach :

```
foreach ($check as $key => $item) {
    $updateData = array('rec_qty' => $total_rec[$key] );                                                        
    $this->dbquery->modUpdatedynamicval('tblstock', 'id', $updateData, $check[$key]);
}
```

So you don't manually check for the `total_rec` value but instead it only checks on submitted `check` post data.

Comment: Your code seems like the output will be the same in my question code. If I input a value for example I input 2 in all textbox and tried to print_r, these are the output 
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 ), But if I skip the first textbox and input the second and third checkbox here's the output 
Array ( [0] => [1] => 2 [2] => 2 ), the first array values are blank, then I f i try to update in query the data that will be pass is also blank.

Comment: @zeus2026 yes it's still passing the empty `total_rec` arrays to the back end, but if you are using the foreach `$check`, it will only pass the `total_rec` with values, so the `modUpdatedynamicval` function will not get any empty `total_rec`

Comment: I have tested using the nested `for` loop just like on your question, and that's the cause of why you only get the last input values when updating the data. Do you want to update the total_rec value on unchecked box as well? or do you want to update only the checked boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Can try with row key (item id). Update your array key with $row->id.

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblstock where process_id = '$process_id'");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){                                       
    ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="opt" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="valueChanged()"> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row->item_code; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->qty_order; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->rec_qty; ?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="last_item_rec[<?php echo $row->id; ?>]"  value="<?php echo $row->rec_qty;  ?>">
        <td><input type="text" name="item_rec[<?php echo $row->id; ?>]"  id="txt" disabled=""></td>  
        <td><input type="text" name="total_rec[<?php echo $row->id; ?>]"></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>  
</tbody>
```

Scenraio Like:

- 1 item Id "2"
- 2 item Id "3"
- 3 item Id "5"

If you check first st row and first row item_id ($row->id) is 2 and enter 7 than you will get array like :-

```
print_r($_POST['total_rec']);
```

Output Like:

```
Array([2]=>7)
```

You can easy to find data using array key

**Update:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">
                System ID:  <b>  <?php echo '12'; ?></b>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Action</th>
                        <th>Item Code </th>
                        <th>Item Description</th>
                        <th>Required QTY Order</th>
                        <th>Last QTY Recieve</th>
                        <th>Item Recieve</th>
                        <th>Total Recieve</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php                   
                    //$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblstock where process_id = '$process_id'");
                    $new_item_list =  array(
                        array('id'=> '1','item_code'=> 'ITEM-1','description' => 'ITEM Desc', 'qty_order'=> '2','rec_qty'=> '2'),
                        array('id'=> '2','item_code'=> 'ITEM-2','description' => 'ITEM Desc 2', 'qty_order'=> '3','rec_qty'=> '3' ),
                        array('id'=> '3','item_code'=> 'ITEM-3','description' => 'ITEM Desc', 'qty_order'=> '5','rec_qty'=> '4' ),
                        array('id'=> '4','item_code'=> 'ITEM-4','description' => 'ITEM Desc', 'qty_order'=> '1','rec_qty'=> '3' )
                    );
                  foreach ($new_item_list as $row){ 
                    ?>  
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>[check]" id="opt" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="valueChanged()"> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['item_code']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['qty_order']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['rec_qty']; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>[last_item_rec]"  value="<?php echo $row['rec_qty'];  ?>">
                        <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>[item_rec]"  id="txt" value='' ></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>[total_rec]" value=''>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                  }
                    ?>  
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Submit Action**: For example

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(isset($value['check'])){
        //Row ID of item table $key
       $total = $value['total_rec'] * $value['item_rec'];
        echo "Total Number :".$total."</br>";
       #here is your update query 
    }    
}
```

Link:- https://prnt.sc/mswdoc
If check checkbook and submit from then you will get output like
Output:- https://prnt.sc/mswefv

Comment: I tried this but it only get the last value of the array.

Comment: If you select all checkbox than you get all value and you select one then get one value

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see, like everybody else is saying, you have trouble in finding the correct rows of checked item. 
I suggest you edit the way you name the form in multidimensional array. bet you didnt know that?

so in view.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>user/recitem_insert">

<div class="box">
<div class="box-header">
<h3 class="box-title">System ID: <b><?php echo $process_id; ?></b></h3>
</div>
<!-- /.box-header -->
<div class="box-body">
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Item Code</th>
<th>Item Description</th>
<th>Required QTY Order</th>
<th>Last QTY Recieve</th>
<th>Item Recieve</th>
<th>Total Recieve</th>



</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php                   

//WTF?? it's 2019. Say hello to SQL Injection
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblstock where process_id = '$process_id'");
foreach ($query->result() as $i=>$row){                                       
?>  

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>][check]" id="opt" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="valueChanged()"> </td>
<td><?php echo $row->item_code; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->qty_order; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->rec_qty; ?></td>

<input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>][last_item_rec]"  value="<?php echo $row->rec_qty;  ?>">

<td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>][item_rec]"  id="txt" disabled=""></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>][total_rec]"></td>  


</tr>

<?php 
}
?>  

</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>

<div class="box-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

and you can easily cycle through the data for each rows while at the same time validating if the checkbox is checked

```
 <?php
//simple way of traversing the data
if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) )
{
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $d )
    {
        //you have all the data here
        //start checking on checked box
        if(isset($d['check']))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '  <td>', $d['last_item_rec'], '</td>';
            echo '  <td>', $d['item_rec'], '</td>';
            echo '  <td>', $d['total_rec'], '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes all have the same ID, which always leads to problems. Change the id of the checkbox in the loop.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="opt-<?php echo $row->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="valueChanged()"> </td>
```